# change asp.net panel visibility based on return value of popup window javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net website. I want to manipulate a webpage based on return value of a confirmation popup.

I have a drop down with some values. "cancel" is one of those values. So when user selects this item, a confirmation box asking user "Are you sure you want to cancel the ticket"? is displayed.

Here is my code,

HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" CssClass="selectstyle" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" onchange ="GetSelectedItem(this);" />

<asp:Panel ID="pnl_Cancel" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <tr>
       <td class="label" align="right">
           Cancellation Reason :
       </td>
       <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="tbxCancellationReason" runat="server" CssClass="selectstyle" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400" Height="50"></asp:TextBox>
       </td>
   </tr>
</asp:Panel>
```

JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedItem(x) {
    if (x.value == 4) {
       if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel support ticket ?") == true) {
           alert("Yes");
           document.getElementById("pnl_Cancel").style.visibility = 'visible';
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

which is displaying a popup as I want.

Now, I want to make a panel visible if user clicked on "OK" and reset dropdownlist if user clicked on "Cancel". I am getting "Yes" alert message but the panel visibility is not working.

Comment: Is panel missing in above code?

Comment: You need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m1gant4n/2/. Register Client IDs of panel and dropdown in server script and use them in javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to do a below things in code-behind file.

1. Register client IDs of pnl_cancel and ddlStatus controls. You will need these client IDs of the controls to access them in JavaScript
2. Add style attribute to pnl_cancel with value display:none. This is to ensure that the control is rendered in HTML but is hidden

[This link here](http://jsfiddle.net/66xvqvmo/) simulates the final rendered HTML. It will help resolve your problem.

`function GetSelectedItem(x) {
    if (x.value == 4) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel support ticket ?")) {
            document.getElementById("pnl_Cancel").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            x.value = "";
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Yes. I did tried above approach. But I am using panel instead of a div. And it's visibility is not working.

Comment: Use `style.display` with **clientID** of `pnl_Cancel` (not `pnl_Cancel` directly). Before that you need to follow first two steps.

Comment: That is done. Just one last thing. Instead of writing x.value = "" in else, how can I store the original value which comes from another aspx page.

Comment: capture the value you want to assign to drop-down do `x.value="capturedvalue"` instead of `x.value = ""`